# Artillery json output differing

Tags: testing, stress-testing, artillery

I am using [artillery](https://artillery.io/) and I am exporting the results as a json file with `-o result.json`

The problem is that it seems that the json files structure are not consistent depending on the **arrivalRate**.

When `arrivalRate=5`, the latencies branch for the intermediate reslts contains 4 fields (see image below).

[image]

When I set arrivalRate to a higher value, for example, `arrivalRate=20` the json response just includes the latency without the other 3 fields. (see image below).

[image]

I would like to get all the information as in the first image.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No @LeoGallucci, I did not.